# Can Troops be flanked?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, flanking

[Troops](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=367) consist of multiple creatures that are handled as a single creature. They have special rules for many things, e.g. being targeted by spells, but nothing in these rules mentions flanking in any way. So, can Troops be flanked in the normal way, or am I missing some rules interaction somewhere? (In Pathfinder 1, Troops could not be flanked, and to me that makes more sense, since the troop is actually multiple creatures and some of them can simply turn around to face whoever is behind them)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Troops can be Flanked

There's no rule stating troops are unable to be flanked, so the  default flanking rules would apply as though the entire troop was one creature.

Troops do have [Troop Defenses](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterAbilities.aspx?ID=44), which have this line:

> Non-damaging effects with an area or that target all creatures in a certain proximity affect a troop normally if they affect the entire area occupied by the troop. **If an effect has a smaller area or numbers of targets, it typically has no effect on the troop.**

If [Flanking](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=458) was a non-damaging effect targeting the troop, then this would prevent it from working on the troop. But 'flanking' doesn't have targets or an area and is instead unique as a circumstance associated to the creature in the middle and both creatures surrounding them, so it seems to avoid the protections under Troop Defenses.

Large scale combat in fiction where troops are attacked from behind by other forces (particularly cavalry) seem to support the conceptual idea allowing such groups of creatures to be flanked and take the AC penalty.